# I have created a testng.xml file where i have mentioned all my class for regress test suite run but not all classes are running through that xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng.xml

Below XML file is not able to run all the methods included in classes on few methods are running.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

 <suite name="Udds_Automation" >
  <test name="Udds_AutomationTest">
     <classes>
        <class name="com.udds.TestCases.InLetOutLet_Oracle_PlatformTest"/>
        <class name="com.udds.TestCases.InLetOutLet_Hive_PlatformTest"/>
        <class name="com.udds.TestCases.OutLet_NonCloud_PlatformTest"/>
        <class name="com.udds.TestCases.Hive_PlatformTest"/>
        <class name="com.udds.TestCases.InLetOutLet_Text_PlatformTest"/>
        <class name="com.udds.TestCases.Mysql_PlatformTest"/>
      <class name="com.udds.TestCases.InLetOutLet_AwsText_PlatformTest"/>
      <class name="com.udds.TestCases.Text_PlatformTest"/>
      <class name="com.udds.TestCases.DataIngestionTest"/>
      <class name="com.udds.TestCases.AwsText_PlatformTest"/>
      <class name="com.udds.TestCases.Oracle_PlatformTest"/>
        <class name="com.udds.TestCases.OutLetPlatformTest"/>
      <class name="com.udds.TestCases.OutLet_AWS_PlatformTest"/>
      <class name="com.udds.TestCases.InLetOutLet_Text_PlatformTest"/>
       </classes>
       </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: Please add your XML content as text into the question. People won't help you having it as an image...

Comment: I have added please check now